# Adding an offset in a $wpdb get results query

Tags: wordpress, offset

```
$post_data=$wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM `ucsite_posts` WHERE `post_type` LIKE 'uc_university_review' order by `post_date` desc LIMIT 1");
```

How would I add an offset of 1 on the above code?

Answer (score -1):

try below code, i hope this will help.

```
echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_short_description', $post->post_excerpt )
```

Comment: This just spits out a an excerpt, I wish to add an offset, starting the query from 2 not the first one.